# PHP Error: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working in CodeIgniter framework and I have tried to apply all the other solutions I found on stack but I could not make it work so here is my problem...
I am trying to retrieve a record from MySQL database table called 'questions' based on uri segment. Then I am trying to display this record in a view. As far as I can tell, the uri segment is passed along everywhere it needs to be, and record is retrieved from database.
The problem comes up when I am trying to access the data from the controller, in my view.
Error I am getting for each echo in my loop in 'view_thread_view' is

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: views/view_thread_view.php

Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

Controller thread

```
function view_thread()
    {
        $quest = $this->uri->segment(3);
        echo $quest;// for checking if uri segment is passed

        if($query = $this->data_model->get_thread($quest))
        {
            $data['records'] = $query;      
        }

        $this->load->view('view_thread_view', $data);
```

Model data_model

```
public function get_thread($quest)
   {
    if($q = $this->db->get_where('questions' , 'qid' , $quest));
    {
      return $q;
    }
   }
```

View view_thread_view

```
<div title="question_view">
    <h1>Question View<h1>
        <?php foreach($records as $data) : ?>
        <div>
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <?php 
            echo $data->title;
            ?>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>Question</h2>
            <?php
            echo $data->contents
            ?>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>Tags</h2>
            <?php
            echo $data->tags
            ?>
        </div>
        <div>
            Thread owner
            <?php
            echo $records->uname
            ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

EDIT: QUESTION ANSWERED

Thanks to Girish Jangid fixed the problem this is the working code:

Controller

```
function view_thread()
    {
        $quest = $this->uri->segment(3);
        echo $quest;// for checking if uri segment is passed
        //$data = array();
        if($query = $this->data_model->get_thread($quest))
        {
            $data['records'] = $query;      
        }

        $this->load->view('view_thread_view', $data);
    }
```

Model

```
public function get_thread($quest)
   {
    if($q = $this->db->get_where('questions' , array('qid' => $quest)));
    {
      return $q;
    }

   }
```

View

```
<div title="question_view">
    <h1>Question View<h1>

        <?php foreach($records->result() as $data) : ?>
        <div>
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <?php 
            echo $data->title;
            ?>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>Question</h2>
            <?php
            echo $data->contents
            ?>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>Tags</h2>
            <?php
            echo $data->tags
            ?>
        </div>
        <div>
            Thread owner
            <?php
            echo $data->uname
            ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is this returning?
$this->data_model->get_thread($quest)

Comment: now that the code is working it is returning a record from the database where 'qid' matches $quest. And $quest contains uri segment(3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should user db function to fetch results, please use CodeIgniter db Query Results functions, like this

```
 if($records->num_rows() > 0){
      foreach($records->result() as $data){
        if(isset($data->title)) echo $data->title;
      }
    }
```

For more detail please read CodeIgniter  Query Result function 
[Query Results](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)

Try this code

```
<div title="question_view">
    <h1>Question View<h1>
        <?php if($records->num_rows() > 0) { ?>  
        <?php foreach($records->result() as $data) : ?>
        <div>
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <?php 
            echo $data->title;
            ?>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>Question</h2>
            <?php
            echo $data->contents
            ?>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>Tags</h2>
            <?php
            echo $data->tags
            ?>
        </div>
        <div>
            Thread owner
            <?php
            echo $records->uname
            ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You do not have to use Active Record functions, you can execute raw queries, which most times is slightly faster than using ActiveRecord.

Comment: You are right, but he have not used result function to fetch records

Comment: This actually seem to work, thank you. 
However, there is the problem with my db query... it must return no results as nothing is displayed in the view. any ideas?

Comment: @Thomas Please try this code in model
$this->db->get_where('questions' , array('qid' => $quest))

Comment: Would love to vote up but not enough rep :(
any ideas about my db problem mentioned above?

Comment: @Thomas, Please check your query manually by this function **echo $this->db->last_query();**

Answer (score -1):

`$records` is an array, not an object, therefore you cannot do `$records->uname`. You probably meant `$data` there too.

Edit: On second look, it appears `$data` is an array as well! Arrays are accessed via `['key']` not `->key`

Also, your code is way over complicated.

```
<?php 
foreach($records as $data){
   $string = <<<STR
   <div>
      <h2>Title</h2>
      {$data['title']}
    </div>
    ...etc
STR;
    echo $string;
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Thx for quick answer, made the code adjustment and I have a new error
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: title

Filename: views/view_thread_view.php

Comment: Try doing `var_dump($data);` in your foreach loop and post the results in your question.

Comment: Answer is wrong, you should use CodeIgniter Query Results functions to retch records.
[link] (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select)

Comment: Ok I see that there is another problem... the query returns this
resource(30) of type (mysql link persistent) resource(37) of type (mysql result) array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { } int(0) int(0) NULL

Comment: So if it is an object and not an array, then use ->key. My answer was that $records is an array.

Comment: `of type (mysql result)` means that it is fetching results @GirishJangid so this answer is NOT wrong.

Comment: If you are using CodeIgniter then you should use CodeIgniter library to fetch records, i konw it's mysql resource object.., but @Jessica gave wrong answer.

Comment: No, No, No! CodeIgniter Database Library should never be 100% relied upon. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14524461/987016 I am tired of people just using something because it 'works' it is a resource hog...